# Why use dispatch_async when using performSegueWithIdentifier in requestAccessToEntity:completion?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, uistoryboardsegue, ekeventstore

When I call the performSegueWithIdentifier in the completion block, if I do not wrap the call in a dispatch_async, it literally takes 10 seconds for the segue to actually happen. However, I can do other things without wrapping them in the same dispatch_async, such as doing core data work, or, logging "things"...

Any insight as to how this works and why... I am lost. If this isn't the right place to ask something like this, I apologize.

```
EKEventStore *store = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
[store requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:self.phaseSegue sender:self];
    });
}];
```

Comment: I was having an issue where the segue load wouldn't fire until the user touched the screen, rather than a 10 second delay, but in the same completion block of requesting access like the question . Wrapping it in the dispatch_async as per the question resolved this problem and the segue performs straight away.

Answer (score 7):

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventKit/Reference/EKEventStoreClassRef/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/EKEventStore/requestAccessToEntityType%3acompletion%3a):

> When the user taps to grant or deny access, the completion handler will be called on an arbitrary queue.

Also, all UI-related stuff **must** be done on the main queue. That's way you need that `dispatch_async`.