# performSegueWithIdentifier method is very slow for modal segue

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue, uistoryboardsegue

I have to show registration view controller. Currently this screen is loaded  with UIWindow.rootViewController method,which I don't like as a solution.

After Google search I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28509252/performseguewithidentifier-very-slow-when-segue-is-modal) question, which doesn't help me at all (problem stays), so I have to ask, are there any other solutions.My code is as follows:

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
  [super viewDidAppear:animated];
  if(![Class isUserRegistered]){
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"" sender:self];
  }
}
```

Registration controller shows after 5-7 seconds (iPhone 4, 7.1.2)

One possible option is to use adaptive segue-s, but this is not possible at the moment.

I notice, that when I remove all outlets from storyboar, view is loading much faster.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Why -1? What is a problem with my question?

Answer (score -1):

Try this,

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    //this block of code is executed on main thread, all UI operations should be done on main thread
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"" sender:self];
});
```

Comment: Tried this, doesn't fix the problem.Segue is still very very slow.