# Swift UIImageView bug when using performSegueWithIdentifier

Tags: swift, uiimageview

I have FirstViewController used to identify user. After user writes data and presses button, request goes to server, if response if positive, I want to open SecondViewController, which contains UIImageView (it's image is declared in Assets).

So when I try to

```
self.performSegueWithIdentifier("openSecond", sender: self)
```

UIImageView is empty. After some time image loads by itself (or if I switch its Highlighted parameter).

If I try to open SecondViewController by button click (using same segue, but from InterfaceBuilder) it opens immediately and the UIImageView shows its image.

There is my UIImageView configuration:
 [image: UIImageView configuration]

How can I fix this?

Comment: May I ask what's the file size of your image "front" ?

Comment: @H4Hugo there are 3 types, 642x416, 1336x866 and 1500x972

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try this :

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier(mysegueIdentifier,sender: self)
})
```

[Some people ran into this kind of problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28509252/performseguewithidentifier-very-slow-when-segue-is-modal), however I cannot explain the real reason for this. Comments and edits welcome.