# Modal segue takes much time on first run

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, autolayout, segue

I noticed that for some weird reason modal segue takes few seconds to perform when triggered in first place. Next time i perform a segue everything is ok.

I'm struggling with this issues for a couple of days and this is what i have discovered so far:

1. **My code has nothing to do with it**. I fully commented my code in source VC ( didSelectRow, prepareForSegue) and destination VC ( viewDidLoad, viewWillAppear )
2. **It doesn't matter if i create a segue in Interface Builder or manually.** As well it doesn't matter how the segue is called ( via performSegue or bind to some button ) ow what is the presentation type. The kind should be modal.
3. **It doesn't matter if destination VC is embedded in Navigation Controller.** And i've found no correlation between presenting VCs ( i call the segue from different VCs and it changes nothing )
4. **Destination VC must have UI elements placed via auto-layout.**
5. And interesting one: **it doesn't matter what is the destination VC**. The lag happens once through entire start, no matter what the exact segue is.

I've tried googling with almost no luck. No solutions from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28509252/performseguewithidentifier-very-slow-when-segue-is-modal/28509716#28509716) helped.

How to reproduce: create a VC with modal form sheet segue ( like i have it in my project ), embed the VC into navigation controller, place some random UI elements \w autolayout via IB ( i haven't tried setting constraints manually yet ), show it via modal segue from anywhere else.

Those arrows you see on example is my testing segues.
[reproduction IB screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P45kZ.png)

I'm using Xcode version 7.2.1 and the app is for iPad.

P.S: english is not my mother tongue, so i apologize for any possible mistakes :)