# Segue very slow on first call in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, segue

I have a few simple Segues --> Show(e.g. Push)

On some Segues the first time calling the Segue I get a delay (about 2 Seconds).

There is no Code being Executed on shouldPerformSegue and prepare.

ViewDidLoad of the next View gets called after the Delay.

When the delay occurs I often get this warning:

```
objc[3993]: Class PLBuildVersion is implemented in both...
```

There seems to be no solution to this though --> [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39520499/class-plbuildversion-is-implemented-in-both-frameworks/39582284#39582284)

I have also tried calling the Segue Manually like this:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "theIdentifier", sender: theSender)
}
```

Is there any way to make this more responsive?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you perform heavy UI task of calling webservice in viewdidload or viewwillappear?

Comment: Seems duplicate question here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28509252/performseguewithidentifier-very-slow-when-segue-is-modal

Comment: Have you tried on real device?

Comment: @Mr.Bista Nah, also viewDidLoad gets called after the delay.

Comment: @AhmadF Yes, same thing

Comment: It can be your next viewcontroller have heavy rendering or heavy execution on `viewDidLoad`, reduce it and try again, I have the same issue with the next viewcontroller contains webview, so i move the webview load to other function

Comment: @Tj3n In one view I do load have a Webview what other function did you move it to?

Comment: I moved webview load to `viewDidAppear`, it may help a bit

Answer (score 0):

Try to embed view controller in a navigation controller